# How to alter view query to display only 5 top records

Tags: views

I couldn't find a similar problem on the forum so I am asking. I created a view with exposed filters but when I visit the view page I am going display 5 top recent record for specific content type. When I click search button the result changes of course and result with a pager shows up. How can I display 5 top recent records before I click search button for the first time when I visit page with the view? I thought to use hook_views_query_alter to add limit to the query but I don't know how. Any ideas how to achieve that?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried limiting the results for the view display?

Comment: Yes, I tried but it doesn't work for me because before you filter the view with exposed filters all records (with 5 on each page) are displayed with a pagination. I want display only top 5 by default without pagination.By the way I use Infinite Scroll instead of a default pager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will show you a sample of how to do it...

In this case if you want to alter the nid to be passed as query to views via filter

```
function hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query){
    switch($view -> name){
        case 'view_name':
            if($view->current_display == 'block'){
                $nids = calculate_nid();
                $nids = !empty($nids) ? $nids : array(0);
                $query->where[1]['conditions'][2]['value'] = $nids;
                $query->where[1]['conditions'][2]['operator'] = 'IN';
            }
            break;
}


function calculate_nid() {
// calculations to get nid. 
// here you can write sql queries
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If within the Views Pager options, you select "Display a specified number of items" and set "Items to display" to 5, you *will* get the behavior you are desiring.  You just need to make sure your sort criteria provides whatever "top" means on your site.  What I *think* you are doing instead is selecting "Use Pager" with 5 items.

Comment: Hi Jimajamma, thank you for your answer but it is not what I want. "Display a specified number of items" with amount of 5 works for each result so when you try find something with exposed filter and query return more than 5 records (for example 10) then only 5 records will be displayed without pagination. Do you know how to modify query adding limit to it with hook_views_query_alter? Thank you!